# « Intérêt à avoir » ou « intérêt d'avoir » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, prépositions

Dans la phrase « L'un des intérêts d'avoir [fait comme cela] », devrait-on plutôt écrire « L'un des intérêts à avoir [fait comme cela] » ou est-ce que la première tournure est correcte ?

Après quelques recherches, il semblerait que l'on dise « intérêt à » et non « intérêt de », mais dans cet exemple, je trouve « de » plus naturel.

Quelle est la règle et quelle est la bonne écriture ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Un parcours rapide du TLFi indique que  l’on dit *avoir intérêt à faire quelque chose*<sup>1</sup> (l’un des derniers points de l’entrée A.1.d).

> On a tout intérêt *à* bien se couvrir en hiver.

Cependant, l’on parle de *l’intérêt de quelque chose* pour désigner ce qui a de l’intérêt dans le *quelque chose* en question (le second point de C).

> Son rhume lui a rappelé l’intérêt de bien se couvrir en hiver.

Ta phrase entre dans le second ; il se trouve juste que ton substantif n’est pas un nom mais un groupe verbal à l’infinitif. Il faut donc dire

> L'un des intérêts d'avoir fait comme cela est […]

---

1. *Avoir intérêt de* est signalé, mais comme usage vieilli.

Comment: SVP, pourriez-vous fournir la traduction anglaise de `un groupe verbal à l’infinitif` ? J'ai hasardé à déceler son sens mais n'y ai pas réussi : https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-a&hs=VVU&rls=org.mozilla:fr:official&q="groupe+verbal+a+l'infinitif"&spell=1&sa=X&ei=2s6SUonFHoiAiQfJ6IDwCA&ved=0CCMQvwUoAA&biw=1366&bih=638

Comment: @LePressentiment A verb phrase whose verb is infinitive.

Answer (score 0):

Il semble qu'il existe une autre distinction entre "intérêt à"et"intérêt de"au niveau du temps de déroulement de l'action.

Comment: Bienvenue sur French Language. Peux-tu préciser cette distinction avec des exemples, s'il te plaît ?